# What is an effective way to disguise an undead riding horse?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, mount, disguise

I am playing a level 7 Necropolitan Dread Necromancer and I am thinking of killing and raising my Light Horse. However, I can't come up with good means to disguise him from the commoners and other party-members. What would be an effective way to achieve this?
I am looking for a relatively cheap way to achieve this, preferably not costing more than 5K gp, and I want to be able to achieve this before hitting level 9.

I have already thought of barding him and using some disguise kits, but that doesn't give me enough certainty. There's also a trick using Magic Jar and a Hat of Disguise, but my character doesn't have a high enough level for it.

Comment: [Very close to a duplicate](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37309/8610), but this *is* narrower.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If appearance is the sole concern, the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *disguise undead* [illus] (*Spell Compendium* 66) does almost exactly what you want *if* you also employ on the creature's behalf a [mundane disguise](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47388/8610). A *wand of disguise undead* (2nd-level spell at caster level 3) costs 4,500 gp.

However, you and others may eventually become aware of the smell; a generous DM may allow the occasional [*gentle repose*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gentleRepose.htm) spell to preserve the undead creature sufficiently to make that less of an issue. It might also be wise to consider a means of concealing the undead creature's [alignment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/undetectableAlignment.htm) as [skeletons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/skeleton.htm) and [zombies](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/zombie.htm) are always neutral evil (which, for example, will strike a paladin as strange if he uses his *detect evil* ability on your otherwise normal-seeming horse).