# What are the limits to a half-dragon using the Disguise Self spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, illusion, dragons, disguise

My understanding is that a [half-dragon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/half-dragon/) *can't* use the spell *[disguise self](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disguise-self/)* to appear human. A half-dragon just has too many limbs for that to work properly, not to mention technically the dragon is no longer humanoid in type.

> Type: Creature type changes to dragon. Do not recalculate hit dice, base attack bonus, or saving throws.

The *disguise self* spell says, "You cannot change your creature type (although you can appear as another subtype)."

Can the *disguise self* spell allow a half-dragon to appear as another Medium dragon, a wyvaran, a drake, or anything similar to dragons?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47388/8610) that deals with mundane disguises.

Comment: I added some links and a quote to back-up that Half-Dragons are not a type of Humanoid. If you don't like the changes, you can roll-back my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can appear as a full Dragon, or another creature that is the Dragon type (including [Wyvaran](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/more-races/advanced-races-11-20-rp/wyvaran-17-rp/)) *as long as* you conform to the other restrictions of *disguise self*. The spell is in no way restricted to Humanoid (except that Humanoids remain Humanoid, and other Types remain their same Type).

> You can seem 1 foot shorter or taller, thin, fat, or in between. [...] the extent of the apparent change is up to you. You could add or obscure a minor feature or look like an entirely different person or gender.

So you could probably pass for a Medium [Young](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-black/young-black-dragon/) metallic or chromatic dragon of your choice, but not a Gargantuan [Great Wyrm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/chromatic-black/black-dragon-great-wyrm/).

---

Side Note: Generally speaking, [Illusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Illusion) spells don't care about things as paltry as number of limbs. Particularly, Glamer spells:

> ...changes a subject’s sensory qualities, making it look, feel, taste, smell, or sound like something else, or even seem to disappear.

If you were, say, an Alchemist with the [Vestigial Arm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/vestigial-arm-ex/) Discovery, you could cover that up with *disguise self* or a similar spell.